# Input on executable file from Python file

Tags: python, executable

My problem is this: I am working on trying to use a Python interface for a program (already made with FORTRAN) so that the user can introduce the input by opening the program and sending the input, but it never works for some reason.

I import the following:

```
import simpleguitk,os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT
```

Using different answers I have already found around here, I have written the following:

```
p = Popen(['potscat2.exe'],stdin=PIPE)#,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
p.communicate(str(opmenu[0])+"\n"+str(opmenu[1])+"\n"+str(opmenu[2])+"\n"+str(opmenu[3][0]*pow(10,opmenu[3][1]))+"\n","UTF-8")
```

Alternatively, there is the following:

```
p = Popen(['potscat2.exe'],stdin=PIPE)#,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
p.stdin.write(str(opmenu[0]))
p.stdin.write(str(opmenu[1]))
p.stdin.write(str(opmenu[2]))
p.stdin.write(str(opmenu[3][0]*pow(10,opmenu[3][1])))
```

Neither of the alternatives works, though.

The former gives this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\simpleguitk\input.py", line 90, in _mouse_click
self._mouse_click_handler(pos)
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 357, in mouse_control
    b.mouse_act(position)
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 106, in mouse_act
    self.action()
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    butF = Button((1050,800),(120,50),"Finish", lambda : finish())
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 280, in finish
    p.communicate(str(opmenu[0])+"\n"+str(opmenu[1])+"\n"+str(opmenu[2])+"\n"+str(opmenu[3][0]*pow(10,opmenu[3][1]))+"\n","UTF-8")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 954, in communicate
    endtime = _time() + timeout
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

The latter gives this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\simpleguitk\input.py", line 90, in _mouse_click
    self._mouse_click_handler(pos)
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 357, in mouse_control
    b.mouse_act(position)
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 106, in mouse_act
    self.action()
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    butF = Button((1050,800),(120,50),"Finish", lambda : finish())
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PythonWorkplace\PotScat\PotScat2.py", line 281, in finish
    p.stdin.write(str(opmenu[0]))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Could anyone help me? Just so you know, I am using **Python 3.4** on Windows 7. The executable has to receive the data one by one, but they are independent from each other.

Help?

**EDIT:** Taking "UTF-8" from the first alternative takes out the TypeError I mentioned (it was counting it as the timeout), but it gives, in exchange, the same TypeError as in the other possibility.

**opmenu** is defined as

```
opmenu = [0,0,0,[0,0]]
```

All the values are integers, save for **opmenu[3][0]**, which is a **float**.

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` you're trying to add a number to a string. check the outputs of converting `opmenu` to `str`. Also, can you give an example `opmenu`?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

This means you are trying to add a number to a string. Trying changing the number to a string type and then add.

Comment: I already got the *TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface* when I tried to give a unicode string where the io system expected a byte array or the inverse. Please say what version of Python you use

Comment: He appears to be using Python 3.4, going by the directory name in his stack trace.

Comment: nEO: I already corrected the 'float' and 'str' error. 

Serge Ballesta: I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: I have fixed that problem, but it is still not working (as you would know if you have paid attention to this message). Can you tell me other possibilities to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
p.communicate(str(opmenu[0])+"\n"+str(opmenu[1])+"\n"+str(opmenu[2])+"\n"+str(opmenu[3][0]*pow(10,opmenu[3][1]))+"\n","UTF-8")
```

The second argument to [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is `timeout`. You are giving it "UTF-8", but that is not a valid value. `timeout` should be a number or `None`.

Try calling `communicate` with just one argument.

```
p.communicate(str(opmenu[0])+"\n"+str(opmenu[1])+"\n"+str(opmenu[2])+"\n"+str(opmenu[3][0]*pow(10,opmenu[3][1]))+"\n")
```